# Typescript - factory pattern

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-conversion, factory

I'm trying to create factory for `MainType`. I would also like to reuse already created types (actually I need same instance) so I store them within `ItemFactory`.

```
class BaseType {

}

class MainType extends BaseType {

}

class ItemFactory {
    items: { [type: string]: BaseType } = {};

    get<T extends BaseType>(type: string): T | null {
        let item = this.items[type];

        if (!item) {
            switch (type) {
                case "main-type":
                    item = new MainType();
                    break;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

            this.items[type] = item;
        }

        return item as T;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify call

```
itemFactory.get<MainType>("main-type"); // current call

// option 1
const resolvedType = itemFactory.get<MainType>();

// option 2
const resolvedType = itemFactory.get("main-type");
```

I would like to have either option 1 or option 2 (no need for both), so I don't have to pass both identifier and type to have correctly resolved resulting type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to give the compiler some kind of mapping between names passed to `itemFactory.get()` and the expected output type.  Mapping from names to types is what `interface`s do best, so you can define one like this:

```
interface NameMap {
  "main-type": MainType;
  // other name-type mappings here
}
```

And then you change your `get()` method to this:

```
  get<K extends keyof NameMap>(type: K): NameMap[K] | null {
    let item = this.items[type];

    if (!item) {
      switch (type) {
        case "main-type":
          item = new MainType();
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }

      this.items[type] = item;
    }

    return item as NameMap[K];
  }
```

You replace `T extends BaseType` to `NameMap[K]` where `K extends keyof NameMap`.  Now the following ("option 2") will work:

```
const resolvedType = itemFactory.get("main-type"); // MainType | null
```

---

Note that you will never get "option 1" to work.  TypeScript's type system gets [erased](http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the JS is emitted, so this:

```
itemFactory.get<MainType>();
```

will become this at runtime:

```
itemFactory.get();
```

And there's no way for *that* to know what to return, since the relevant information has been left behind before the code started running.  This is intentional; it is [not a goal of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) to "add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system."  Instead, TypeScript should "encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata"... in this case it means using a runtime value like the string `"main-type"` instead of a design-time type like `MainType` to keep track of what `get()` should do.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMAqBPADg6BvAUNaARoqhtALzQBEKArmpQNw4C+OOokMAsmAJYB2JTAgAeAFwT8AJjHgRk6TLnwBbPoMXkqEGgCcEjFmwETdAMzDBMAOTAqEPNNjxU1AgLRjFlAFzQeAkJM+JRE8p7efnIKGEys7OBQ0ACSEioAYpZiAPa6KM74vGkQfljQANpeGH4QYroCAOYAulHEmsxaWMxMLg0IYgA8ANLQohLSMADWCCjZZtC29o4AfAAUVQh+QwCUfosOYGjlQ03QAD7Q-DQgIAX40CD90EUIKlpiABa8EAB0LyoQSqKJo9e7PearACE-22dzBEAA7kVgB9oOtFLDlGD7sBEK51BEML4XNj7v8tPwEAj-OohKttsFSfcCPowJNGaSpAgLNcxD4SUz9GI9PxLtcQBz7vFSZ9vn9ikCMKcKP9JdL7kKRc80tBIAs7AcjidGax4sBsvxatrXplgDk8hSqSk0rb7Sh6T1zZaxNB9BBsiAAG4IKRCLT-V25FA-PpiVaUNz8QkGBk4IA)